# I want to create a contact form using html5 localStorage. but did not work delete and Remove all button? also can not save gender data

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I'm unable to `save gender data` and unable to `delete particular data or clear all data`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  contactsNamespace.initialize();
  $('#removeAll').on('click', removeAll, false);
});

(function () {
  this.contactsNamespace = this.contactsNamespace || {};
  var ns = this.contactsNamespace;
  var currentRecord;

  ns.initialize = function () {
    $('#btnSave').on('click', ns.save);
    ns.display();
  };

  function retrieveFromStorage() {
    var contactsJSON = localStorage.getItem('contacts');
    return contactsJSON ? JSON.parse(contactsJSON) : [];
  }
  ns.display = function () {
    $('#currentAction').html('Add Contact');
    currentRecord = { key: null, contact: {} };
    displayCurrentRecord();
    var results = retrieveFromStorage();
    bindToGrid(results);
  };
  function bindToGrid(results) {
    var html = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var contact = results[i];
      html += '<tr><td>' + contact.email + '</td>';
      html += '<td>' + contact.firstName + ' ' + contact.lastName + '</td>';
      html += '<td><a class="edit" href="javascript:void(0)" data-key=' + i + '>Edit</a>' + '|' + '<a class="delete" href="javascript:void(1)" data-key=' + i + '>Delete</a></td></tr>';
    }
    html = html || '<tr><td colspan="4">No records available</td></tr>';
    $('#contacts tbody').html(html);
    $('#contacts a.edit').on('click', ns.loadContact);
    $('#contacts a.delete').on('click', ns.deleteContact);
  }
  ns.loadContact = function () {
    var key = parseInt($(this).attr('data-key'));
    var results = retrieveFromStorage();
    $('#currentAction').html('Edit Contact');
    currentRecord = { key: key, contact: results[key] }
    displayCurrentRecord();
  };
  function displayCurrentRecord() {
    var contact = currentRecord.contact;
    $('#studentId').val(contact.studentId);
    $('#firstName').val(contact.firstName);
    $('#lastName').val(contact.lastName);
    $('#email').val(contact.email);
    $('.radiobtn').val(contact.radiobtn);
    $('#phoneNumber').val(contact.phoneNumber);
  }
  ns.save = function () {
    var contact = currentRecord.contact;
    contact.studentId = $('#studentId').val();
    contact.firstName = $('#firstName').val();
    contact.lastName = $('#lastName').val();
    contact.email = $('#email').val();
    contact.radiobtn = $('.radiobtn').val();
    contact.phoneNumber = $('#phoneNumber').val();
    var results = retrieveFromStorage();
    if (currentRecord.key != null) {
        results[currentRecord.key] = contact;
    }
    else {
        results.push(contact);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(results));
    function removeAll() {
        localStorage.clear('contacts');
    }
    ns.display();
  };
})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: Arial;
}

aside, footer, header, hgroup, nav {
  display: block;
}

body {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  height: 35px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#headerText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding-left: 26em;
  /*float: right;*/
}

div[role="main"] {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

#editContact {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#editContact h2 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 200px;
}

#editContact div {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#editContact div.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

#editContact label {
  width: 150px;
  height: 12px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#editContact input {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 2px;
}

#editContact div.radiobtn input {
  width: 16px;
  height: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#contacts {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#contacts thead {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  color: #7C756D;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

#contacts tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <header>
      <hgroup id="headerText">
          <h1>Contacts</h1>
          <h3><a id="removeAll" href="javascript:void(0)">Remove All</a></h3>
      </hgroup>
  </header>
  <div role="main">
    <table id="contacts">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <form>
      <div id="editContact">
        <h2 id="currentAction"></h2>
      <div>
        <label for="studentId">Student Id: </label>
        <input type="number" id="studentId" name="studentId" required/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email Address: </label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <label for="gender">Gender: </label>
        <input type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" value="Male" />Male
        <input type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" value="Female" />Female
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="phoneNumber">Contact: </label>
        <input type="number" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required pattern="{11}"/>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="btnSave">Save</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you only link the relevant parts of code?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, the gender and all fields are editable and savable, I checked this with a few testcases, can you please check the below JSFiddle, I fixed the `removeAll` functionality, by removing the third parameter in the `.click()` function and placing the `.Click()` function in the initialization block instead. also the `removeAll()` function was placed inside another function and could not be found by the calling function.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  contactsNamespace.initialize();
});

(function() {
  this.contactsNamespace = this.contactsNamespace || {};
  var ns = this.contactsNamespace;
  var currentRecord;

  ns.initialize = function() {
    $('#btnSave').on('click', ns.save);
    $('#removeAll').on('click', ns.removeAll);
    ns.display();
  };
  ns.removeAll = function() {
    console.log("revmoing");
    localStorage.clear('contacts');
    ns.display();
  }

  function retrieveFromStorage() {
    var contactsJSON = localStorage.getItem('contacts');
    return contactsJSON ? JSON.parse(contactsJSON) : [];
  }
  ns.display = function() {
    $('#currentAction').html('Add Contact');
    currentRecord = {
      key: null,
      contact: {}
    };
    displayCurrentRecord();
    var results = retrieveFromStorage();
    bindToGrid(results);
  };

  function bindToGrid(results) {
    var html = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var contact = results[i];
      html += '<tr><td>' + contact.email + '</td>';
      html += '<td>' + contact.firstName + ' ' + contact.lastName + '</td>';
      html += '<td><a class="edit" href="javascript:void(0)" data-key=' + i + '>Edit</a>' + '|' + '<a class="delete" href="javascript:void(1)" data-key=' + i + '>Delete</a></td></tr>';
    }
    html = html || '<tr><td colspan="4">No records available</td></tr>';
    $('#contacts tbody').html(html);
    $('#contacts a.edit').on('click', ns.loadContact);
    $('#contacts a.delete').on('click', ns.deleteContact);
  }
  ns.loadContact = function() {
    var key = parseInt($(this).attr('data-key'));
    var results = retrieveFromStorage();
    $('#currentAction').html('Edit Contact');
    currentRecord = {
      key: key,
      contact: results[key]
    }
    displayCurrentRecord();
  };

  function displayCurrentRecord() {
    var contact = currentRecord.contact;
    $('#studentId').val(contact.studentId);
    $('#firstName').val(contact.firstName);
    $('#lastName').val(contact.lastName);
    $('#email').val(contact.email);
    $('.radiobtn').val(contact.radiobtn);
    $('#phoneNumber').val(contact.phoneNumber);
  }

  ns.save = function() {
    var contact = currentRecord.contact;
    contact.studentId = $('#studentId').val();
    contact.firstName = $('#firstName').val();
    contact.lastName = $('#lastName').val();
    contact.email = $('#email').val();
    contact.radiobtn = $('.radiobtn').val();
    contact.phoneNumber = $('#phoneNumber').val();
    var results = retrieveFromStorage();
    if (currentRecord.key != null) {
      results[currentRecord.key] = contact;
    } else {
      results.push(contact);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(results));
    ns.display();
  };
})();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but one problem is solve from three. still now i'm unable to store gender data and did not work delete option.

Comment: @BasherSarkar Does all the functionality work fine? any problems with the code?

Comment: yes. still now i'm unable to store gender data and did not work delete option. @Naren_Murali